# How to Select Upload Button and Specify a Path for Document Upload in Selenium with Python

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver, browser-automation

So I have to select the upload button on a page that is opened from a new page after clicking the edit button on the prior page. As it opens a new page, I have to select the file to upload by selecting the Here is the trace back I get when I try to select that element:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File ".\skyward_collegeboard_TSI_import.py", line 143, in <module>
    element = WebDriverWait(browser, 20).until(
  File "C:\Python38\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\support\wait.py", line 80, in until
    raise TimeoutException(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.TimeoutException: Message:
```

The file upload element is this:

```
<input type="file" name="file1" id="file1" tabindex="55" size="76" det="true">
```

The button to confirm the upload is this:

```
<a class="button" id="bUpload" tabindex="60" href="javascript:if (cbs(&quot;bUpload&quot;)) {Attach();}" role="button">Upload</a>
```

The save button element to confirm the upload to the server is this:

```
<a class="button" id="bSave" tabindex="500" href="javascript:if (cbs(&quot;bSave&quot;)) {checkSave(&quot;EditImport&quot;,&quot;simpthttp000.w&quot;,&quot;close&quot;);}" role="button" style=""><span class="hkey">S</span>ave</a>
```

You can see a picture of the buttons and the page where I have to select the file below:
[image]

The main code that is driving this is built on python and the selenium package because the program we are using does not have any API nor is it built using modern web application stacks. I have tried using `XPATH`, `NAME`, `CSS_SELECTOR`, and `ID` to click this button to be able to select the document to upload. However, I have not had much success.

The main code controlling this can be found here: https://github.com/Richard-Barrett/ITDataServicesInfra/blob/master/Python/Skyward/skyward_collegeboard_TSI_import.py

The snippet controlling this button click:

```
# Upload Test File
# Choose File Button XPATH = //*[@id='file1']
element = WebDriverWait(browser, 20).until(
            EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.NAME, "file1")))
element.click();
```

As mentioned, I have tried `NAME`, `XPATH`, and `ID` to which none of them have worked. 
I have even tried to write a one-liner to select this button so I can move onto the next step to upload, then click save.

Update: Tried Switching to the Window as there are three windows in total. Furthermore, I tried the answer mentioned below by @supputuri and got the following traceback.

```
  File ".\skyward_collegeboard_TSI_import.py", line 151, in <module>
    element.send_keys("C:\Imports\CustomNameNeedsFormatting_02_24_2020_20_14_12_richardbarrett")
  File "C:\Python38\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webelement.py", line 477, in send_keys
    self._execute(Command.SEND_KEYS_TO_ELEMENT,
  File "C:\Python38\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webelement.py", line 633, in _execute
    return self._parent.execute(command, params)
  File "C:\Python38\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 321, in execute
    self.error_handler.check_response(response)
  File "C:\Python38\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\errorhandler.py", line 242, in check_response
    raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.InvalidArgumentException: Message: invalid argument: File not found : C:\Imports\CustomNameNeedsFormatting_02_24_2020_20_14_12_richardbarrett
  (Session info: chrome=80.0.3987.122)
```

The code that is now handling that issue to switch to the third window is:

```
# Upload Test File
# Choose File Button XPATH = //*[@id='file1']
# Window Page Address that Opens = https://skyward-student.del-valle.k12.tx.us/scripts/wsisa.dll/WService=wsEAplus/simptedit000.w?isPopup=true
# Browser Switches to Window
WebDriverWait(browser,10).until(EC.number_of_windows_to_be(3))
browser.switch_to.window(browser.window_handles[-1])
#upload = browser.find_element_by_id("file1")
#upload.send_keys(r"C:\Users\richard.barrett\Downloads\CustomNameNeedsFormatting_02_24_2020_20_14_12_richardbarrett")
element = WebDriverWait(browser, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//*[@id='file1']")))
element.send_keys("C:\Imports\CustomNameNeedsFormatting_02_24_2020_20_14_12_richardbarrett")
```

Here is the specific elements that I need to interact with from the Selenium IDE Recording:

```
{
      "id": "2193d953-a105-45d0-8e6f-7fa910863cc2",
      "comment": "",
      "command": "click",
      "target": "id=file1",
      "targets": [
        ["id=file1", "id"],
        ["name=file1", "name"],
        ["css=#file1", "css:finder"],
        ["xpath=//input[@id='file1']", "xpath:attributes"],
        ["xpath=//div[@id='pageContentWrap']/table/tbody/tr/td/fieldset/table/tbody/tr[9]/td/fieldset/table/tbody/tr/td[2]/table/tbody/tr/td/input", "xpath:idRelative"],
        ["xpath=//td[2]/table/tbody/tr/td/input", "xpath:position"]
      ],
      "value": ""
    }, {
      "id": "2f5cfebb-5e97-42da-97c6-2f7880fc2ec5",
      "comment": "",
      "command": "type",
      "target": "id=file1",
      "targets": [
        ["id=file1", "id"],
        ["name=file1", "name"],
        ["css=#file1", "css:finder"],
        ["xpath=//input[@id='file1']", "xpath:attributes"],
        ["xpath=//div[@id='pageContentWrap']/table/tbody/tr/td/fieldset/table/tbody/tr[9]/td/fieldset/table/tbody/tr/td[2]/table/tbody/tr/td/input", "xpath:idRelative"],
        ["xpath=//td[2]/table/tbody/tr/td/input", "xpath:position"]
      ],
      "value": "C:\\fakepath\\CustomNameNeedsFormatting_02_24_2020_20_14_12_richardbarrett.csv"
    },
```

Comment: So I tried the suggestion on the answer by @supputuri however, I see that I wasn't switching to that window page, but I am still have the issue of selecting the element ```  File ".\skyward_collegeboard_TSI_import.py", line 151, in <module>
    element.send_keys("C:\Imports\CustomNameNeedsFormatting_02_24_2020_20_14_12_richardbarrett")
  File "C:\Python38\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webelement.py", ``` I think it is an error with send_keys

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Send the file path to the element.

```
element = WebDriverWait(browser, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.NAME, "file1")))
# don't click on the element, just send the path directly
element.send_keys("File/path/goes/here")
```

Comment: Yeah @supputuri it doesn't seem to work I am getting something similar to the trace back already mentioned. ```Traceback (most recent call last):
  File ".\skyward_collegeboard_TSI_import.py", line 144, in <module>
    element = WebDriverWait(browser, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.NAME, "file1")))
  File "C:\Python38\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\support\wait.py", line 80, in until
    raise TimeoutException(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.TimeoutException: Message:```

Comment: Tried the same method with XPATH that didn't work either.

Comment: I was able to get it to work using the above code after I set the element to be enabled.